# spark data modified after using random in filter method

Tags: apache-spark

```
    val list = List("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C")
    val df1 = sc.parallelize(list).toDF("key").withColumn("feature", lit("u4")).select("feature", "key").groupBy(col("feature"), col("key")).count()
    val df2 = sc.parallelize(list).toDF("key").withColumn("feature", lit("u5")).select("feature", "key").groupBy(col("feature"), col("key")).count()
    val df = df1.unionAll(df2)
    df.show

    val udf_sample = udf { (x: String) => {
      Math.random() < 0.3
    }
    }
    df.filter(udf_sample(col("feature"))).show()
```

the output is:

```
+-------+---+-----+
|feature|key|count|
+-------+---+-----+
|     u4|  A|    1|
|     u4|  B|    3|
|     u4|  C|    5|
|     u5|  A|    1|
|     u5|  B|    3|
|     u5|  C|    5|
+-------+---+-----+

+-------+---+-----+
|feature|key|count|
+-------+---+-----+
|     u4|  A|    1|
|     u4|  C|    2|
|     u5|  A|    1|
|     u5|  B|    1|
|     u5|  C|    2|
+-------+---+-----+
```

note in the second dataframe, the count column values are different from those in the first dataframe. While I expect to random filter some Rows.

Answer (score 0):

It's filtering the feature before the grouping by. Spark is lazy so no transformation (filter, group) is performed until an action (print, count) is found.  There is a good article about this [here](https://medium.com/@aristo_alex/how-apache-sparks-transformations-and-action-works-ceb0d03b00d0)

When an action is found, Spark tries to optimize the transformations to be applied, so it will run the filters first to try to reduce how many data it needs to process:

Although cache is not an action, it will do the trick as well, since when an action is found, it will compute the DAG until the cache, and then utilise the result in further computation

You can cache the `df` to the filter be performed after the groupBy

**INPUT**

```scala
df.show
+-------+---+-----+
|feature|key|count|
+-------+---+-----+
|     u4|  C|    5|
|     u4|  A|    1|
|     u4|  B|    3|
|     u5|  C|    5|
|     u5|  A|    1|
|     u5|  B|    3|
+-------+---+-----+
```

**DEFINING THE UDF**

```
scala> val udf_sample = udf { (x: String) => {
     |       Math.random() < 0.3
     |     }
     |     }
udf_sample: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,BooleanType,Some(List(StringType)))
```

**OUPUT**

```
df.cache

df.filter(udf_sample(col("feature"))).show()
+-------+---+-----+
|feature|key|count|
+-------+---+-----+
|     u4|  C|    5|
|     u4|  B|    3|
|     u5|  C|    5|
+-------+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks. I use persist() to cache the df, and it does work for this example. But it doesn't work for big data.  Does persist or cache will not work for big data?

Comment: If I use the "count" column like udf { (x: String,count:Long) => {   Math.random() < 0.3  } }, it seems that cache is not needed.